# Refactoring LINQ to Query Expressions

Tags: c#, linq

How can I refactor this LINQ to a Query Expression ??

```
    private static IEnumerable GetNameOccurrence(IEnumerable<string> allNames)
    {
        var nameTest = allNames.GroupBy(n => n).
            Select(group =>
                new
                {
                    Name = group.Key,
                    Count = group.Count()
                }).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count);

        return nameTest;
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear, which part, the `GetNameOccurance` method or it's contents?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 private static IEnumerable GetNameOccurrence(IEnumerable<string> allNames)
 {
    var nameTest = 
    (from name in allNames
    group name by name.n into nameGroup
    select new { Name = nameGroup.Key, Count = nameGroup.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(nameGroup => nameGroup.Count);

    return nameTest;
}
```

Comment: You can condense that into a "1 liner" by replacing `var nameTest = ` with `return`.

Comment: Yeah, I would do it that way, too. But I was trying to stick with his style.